# How to properly import a shared variable?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, import, module, global-variables

I am having the following 3 Python files:

**a.py**:

```py
myvar = 1
   
def increment():
    global myvar
    myvar += 1
```

**b.py**:

```py
import a
    
a.increment()
print(a.myvar)
```

**c.py**:

```py
from a import increment, myvar
    
increment()
print(myvar)
```

Now when I run `b.py` and `c.py` independently, I get:

```
python3 ./b.py
2
python3 ./c.py
1
```

Can you explain the difference?

Thanks!

This is `Python 3.7.3` on the latest Debian GNU/Linux (stable).

Answer (score 0):

The overall reason is that **integers are immutable**.

Let me explain.
In your `c.py` script, a variable `myvar` is imported from the module `a`, and then, the `increment()` method is called on `a.myvar` doing `myvar += 1` in module `a`. Since we have the reference to `myvar` already, and integers are immutable, Python can't set that reference to the new value.
The reassignment happened only in module `a`.

To get the updated value after `increment()`, you should also import your module `a`, and try to access the reference directly via `a.myvar`

**NOTE** that `c.py` will work correctly if `myvar` was any of `list,dict,set`, or other mutable objects.

Here's the updated `c.py`, which works correctly on integers.

```py
import a
from a import increment, myvar

increment()
print(myvar)

print(a.myvar)
```

And here's an `a.py` example with mutable ojbects. Try it with the same `c.py` and see how it works.

```py
# a.py
myvar = ["some"]

def increment():
    global myvar
    myvar.append("thing")
```